# 'Expected indent error' while making a text story in IDLE with Python

Tags: python, indentation

I received an "expected indent error" from idle, while programming in python. I am trying to make a text story.

Here is my code:

```
import time
choice1 = input("you walk into a haunted house, do you take door #1 or door #2?(1/2)")
if choice1 == "1":
        door1 = input("You see a staircase... go up or down? (up/down)")
        if door1 == ("up"):

        if door1 == ("down"):
            print ("AHHHHHHHH.....")
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("AHHHHHHHH.....")
            time.sleep(1)print (".........")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("THUNK. you slipped off the ladder and died because you fell for so long")
if choice1 == "2":
        print ("ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("oooff, you fell into a dark room, try to find your flashlight or wander around? (flashlight/wander)")
```

Comment: Why are the if bodies so far in? Why does an if have no body? Why is your indenting inconsistent?

Comment: after if door1 == ("up")  add pass

Comment: separate this: time.sleep(1)print (".........") in 2 lines

Comment: In the future, Include the information as to the line where an error occurs.  Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  The mcve for this code is `if door1:\nif door2:`, which results in `SyntaxError: expected an indented block`.

Answer (score 2):

You must be careful with the indentation, python is severe in it, you must add some statement after an if statement, try with `pass`. In addition, it separates each sentence into a line.

```
import time

choice1 = input("you walk into a haunted house, do you take door #1 or door #2?(1/2)")

if choice1 == "1":
        door1 = input("You see a staircase... go up or down? (up/down)")
        if door1 == ("up"):
            pass
        if door1 == ("down"):
            print ("AHHHHHHHH.....")
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("AHHHHHHHH.....")
            time.sleep(1)
            print (".........")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("THUNK. you slipped off the ladder and died because you fell for so long")
if choice1 == "2":
        print ("ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("oooff, you fell into a dark room, try to find your flashlight or wander around? (flashlight/wander)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Each block is supposed to have code beneath it so

```
if door1 == ("up"):
```

can be changed to

```
if door1 == ("up"): 
     pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because you have a block with no statements in it.

Python syntax requires code blocks after if, except, def, class etc.

Here, the  `if door1 == ("up"):` is empty.

if nothing has to be done in a code block, a `pass` is included in such a block to not produce an `IndentationError`.

**The pass statement does nothing**. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.

In your code, use this

```
if door1 == ("up"): 
     pass
```